# Deploying Rails to Elastic Beanstalk, nodejs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hosting

I want to host my app on a VPC EC2 instance with AWS, and this line in the documentation has me somewhat confused:

> Install nodejs to allow the Rails server to run locally:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

I was just wondering why I need nodejs at all, let alone to allow the rails server to run locally since i thought that this was already handled by WEBrick.

Heres a link to the documentation in question:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html

Answer (score 0):

Rails uses a Javascript runtime for certain tasks (generating scaffolds and compiling templates among others). You do not need to use nodejs, you can add other runtimes as gems in your Gemfile, e.g. `therubyracer`, `therubyrhino`. (YMMV on EC2, if it suggests using nodejs, I would install it unless you have a good reason not to)

Comment: Hmmm, I'm somewhat confused now, how come I haven't run across anything like this when deploying rails apps to heroku in the past?

Comment: Also, from what I've read about nodejs it seems to be used *instead* of rails, which is also causing me some confusion

Comment: I'll also add that I'm using osx and not ubuntu which the tutorial is based off of, does that make a difference?

Comment: I think that heroku probably has a JS runtime available by default. NodeJS can be used to create web applications, but it can also be used to execute any sort of application written in javascript. On either osx or ubuntu you will need to have a javascript runtime for Rails. Rails uses [execJS](https://github.com/rails/execjs), if you consult the documentation there it should help.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks @Slicedpan this is starting to make better sense. If you dont mind answering another question(s)... Is this runtime only used for non local hosting? I dont have any runtimes declared in my gemfile but I'm still able to set up a localhost rails server. Also what documentation are you talking about (rails? execJS?).

Comment: I'll also add that other tutorials ive found seem to omit this step.

Comment: If you have nodejs installed, you won't need to add anything to your gemfile. You need the runtime wherever you are running rails (unless you want to do some serious hacking). The linked doc is what I was talking about, it explains how the execjs gem (that is a dependency of rails) locates javascript runtimes, and which ones are supported

Answer (score 0):

The title of the question is unclear. Elasticbeanstalk *uses* EC2 instances but you should never ssh directly into an EC2 server to make changes.

Elasticbeanstalk will destroy and create EC2 instances to scale with the web traffic coming to the application. Making changes to one particular instance will not guarantee it will make the changes for all of the EC2 instances belonging to one Elasticbeanstalk application.

Also that particular instance can be destroyed when deploying, or rebuilding or when the app scales back down.

If you're using the Ruby platform on Elasticbeanstalk you'll need to use their builtin in EB extensions to either run a command to install node or use the yum package manager to install it.

Here's documentation that describes the yum method:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-packages